# ModelPopupExtender not showing from code behind on pageLoad

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, modalpopupextender

I need to display popup when page loads. I have used ModelPopupExtender. It does shows on it's TargetControlID click but not showing on page load from code behind.
I have check many solutions on stack but none of them are working for me.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.mpOTP.Show();
}

 <asp:Button ID="activateMpOtp" runat="server" Text="Open" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpOTP" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="popup-overlay" PopupControlID="pnlOTP" CancelControlID="closeOTP" TargetControlID="activateMpOtp"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>

    <asp:Panel ID="pnlOTP" runat="server" CssClass="popup-dialogue">
    </asp:Panel>
```

Getting this error in console
[image]

Comment: Are you using AJAXControlToolKit?

Comment: @Sunil Yes. Downloaded from nuget manager

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your markup is not correct.

First of all, you need to register AjaxControlToolKit controls by using the following directive at the top of your page markup, just after the page directive.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="act %>
```

Then, your markup should look like the following. Problems with your markup are listed below.

- You have not included markup for the cancel button
- and also your control prefix is wrong since it should not be `asp` which is the prefix is for ASP.Net Microsoft controls and not for AJAXControlToolKit (NOTE: you give this prefix in your register directive for AjaxControl,Toolkit, which is `act` in code sample given, but you could give any prefix and use it for modalpopuextender)

**Correct markup for ModalPopupExtender**

```
<asp:Button ID="activateMpOtp" runat="server" Text="Open" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
<act:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpOTP" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="popup-overlay"
         PopupControlID="pnlOTP" CancelControlID="closeOTP"
         TargetControlID="activateMpOtp"></act:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlOTP" runat="server" CssClass="popup-dialogue">
  <div class="header">
    Modal Popup
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    Your content goes here
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="closeOTP" runat="server" Text="Close" />
 </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: I have not mentioned full page code. but I did register AjaxControlToolKit on my content page. Whatever prefix I have defined that I have used. Other thing is It is working with TargetControlID. I just need to call it from code behind when page loads.

Comment: Ok. So I have not defined cancel button id in mark up so it was not working. Thanks for help

Comment: Don't use `asp` for tag prefix for AJAXControlToolkit since that is used for Microsoft controls. So it's best to use a non-conflicting prefix like `act` or `cc1` or anything that you like. It's just good programming practice.

Comment: Yes, you already had the correct server-side code. One thing you could change in your server-side code is to call the Show method only when Page.IsPostBack == false, so your code should look like `if(!Page.IsPostBack) {  this.mpOTP.Show(); }`